# Electron-Forge SQLite3 database not accessible on MacOS Darwin build after unzipping

Tags: macos, sqlite, sequelize.js, electron-forge

I'm having some issues with a CRUD desktop application I developed with the help of a freelancer.  It's an electron-forge build that works seamlessly on Windows 10, and works on MacOS initially when accessing the out folder, the strange thing happens when:

1. I use `npm run publish` to zip the Mac/Darwin instance
2. I manually package.zip the results of `npm run make`

When I do this, and unzip the file to run, the SQLite integration fails completely.  The app appears to be working upon start, but no changes can be made to the DB objects, nor can new objects be made.

The freelancer who put together the DB integration said he was not able to solve this issue, but it's impossible to put apps in marketplaces without zipping the application for delivery.  I can post code if necessary, I just don't even know what aspect of the code would be relevant, and feel like there has to be something I can install/put in my  `package.json` that might solve this, but I'm just not sure.

Here is my package.json file in case that is helpful:

```
{
  "name": "C",
  "productName": "C",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": {
    "name": "A",
    "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
  },
  "license": "NA",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "icon": "src/images/n.ico"
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "C"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "ebay-oauth-nodejs-client": "^1.2.1",
    "electron-better-ipc": "^1.1.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-store": "^7.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "json-csv": "^3.0.6",
    "sequelize": "^6.5.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "electron": "10.1.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by simply creating a DMG target (see https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/dmg) that I did not need to worry about unzipping process.  I believe DMG is the ideal approach for packaging Mac OS apps that have something like a SQLite database integration within.